# How to use SATA disk and IDE disk in one PC?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, sata, ata

I have a PC with two disks.
The 1st disk is SATA (160 GB) with Windows XP on it.
The 2nd disk is IDE (80 GB) with data on it.

When I turn on the PC, Windows XP starts but I can only see the 1st disk in Windows, not the 2nd one.

When I get into BIOS I can see that the 2nd disk is actually connected and recognized.

[image: BIOS-IDE detected]

What should I do, so that I can use both disks in Windows?

Comment: Are all drivers installed? Anything suspicious in the _Device Manager_?

Comment: Is the IDE controller visible in Device Manager ? Do you have "unknown devices" in Device Manager ? Are you sure Master/Slave setting is correct on the IDE drive? I've seen numerous cases where a system would initially work for a few years with bad master/slave setings and stopped working at some point when the electronics componets got older.

Comment: And make sure that the IDE drive is on the END connector of the IDE cable. Not on the middle one. The motherboard is on the other end. The middle connector is ONLY for a slave drive (if present).

Comment: I can only see one disk in your BIOS image.

Comment: SATA does not have the concept of Master-Slave, are you 100% positive, your system even supports SATA drives.  SATA and IDE are not compatible with one another.  The WDC WD800BB-22JHC0 is a PATA (might be ATA depending on it's age) HDD which is not compatible and completely different than SATA.

Comment: Make and model of PC?

Comment: So how's the jumper on the IDE drive? And how is it connected?

Comment: Are you sure it's the 160 GB SATA drive that's visible in Windows, not the 80 GB IDE one?

Comment: On PCs this old, the SATA controller was usually a third-party SATA FakeRAID controller. You won’t find its hard drives in BIOS setup.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not mention the use of using an additional controller card I assume you have a mainboard that provides SATA and IDE support, sometimes using additional chips. In this case you have to search other places in your BIOS for settings like:
"enhanced mode/compatible mode"
"PATA1 + PATA2"
"PATA + SATA"

You have to select a mode that supports both type of drives like "enhanced mode" or "PATA + SATA".

It is possible that you may switch off the "AHCI" setting.

Your documentation is very poor. Please try to provide the name and manufacturer of your mainboard either by looking at it or running for any further information.

Sometimes additional chips on the board can be switched on and off.
You need the on position.